# Magento 2: layered navigation filter query (code)

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation, search

I want to get the layered navigation filter query which applies on products according to the attribute value. I want to change that query. How can I get that piece of code where query is appling?

The url is `http://127.0.0.1/ncsmokehouse/shop/bacon.html?product_or_type=64`.

I would like to change `product_or_type=64` for my own query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class

> Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item

Below function **$query** is making it

```
/**
     * Get filter item url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        $query = array(
            $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
            Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
        );
        return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
    }
```

Comment: can i get in which tables this query fetch the data?  i want to change the tables where this query fetch the data .

Comment: This is not the database query this is parameter of url after questionmark(?)

Comment: from where these parameter filter the products ?